# How to get a tableview to be the one like in youtube app for iPad?

Tags: uitableview, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to create an app that looks like the youtube app. I wanna have the tableview on the right or the object at index:1. I tried doing it but the problem is that My tableview is going off the bounds. I cant see the text in them?

Comment: I think the question is that the tableview in youtube  rearranges itself during orientation.An interesting idea would be to think of that kind of a TableView

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking about the 'tableview' on the right or object at Index:1.

But the YouTube app appears to simply be using a custom UITableViewCell object.  You can create these easily in Interface Builder (or programmatically) and then return them in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

You can create the tableview cell either in the same NIB file as the parent view or in a separate file.

Note that if you create your own table cell, you will probably want to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath (tableView delegate method) and just return
  self.myCell.frame.height;